# How can I create a screen shot with emphasis?

Tags: macos, screenshot

[image]

How can I create a screen shot like the above? I am using a Mac.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)

- Select the oval tool
- Make sure the edge settings are fuzzy
- Select the areas you want to put emphasis
- Invert selection
- Select Fill tool
- Set to color and include alpha settings ("alpha" is transparency)
- And fill the selected area outside the ovals.

Comment: This can be done in Photoshop as well with nearly the exact same steps.

Comment: Or probably any half way decent paint package.

Answer (score 2):

The Omni Group (developer of OmniGraffle) has a great free Mac app called **[OmniDazzle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidazzle/)** that was created solely for the purpose of highlighting areas of your screen.

It comes with a set of 10+ screen effects that can be activated using keyboard shortcuts, mouse gestures or the menubar icon. For the task you described—"screen shot with emphasis"—the *Focal Point*, *Cutout* and *Flashlight* effects would all work. And you can configure things like border size/color, shading level, etc. in a settings panel. (Other effects of note: *Scribble* and *Zoom*, which do exactly what you'd expect.)

I've used/tried Gimp, Photoshop, Pixelmator, Skitch, Aviary and a handful of other methods to handle tasks like the one you described, and so far OmniDazzle is the easiest and most convenient. Skitch would be my #2 choice, but that's a much bigger app with a comprehensive set of capture + edit + upload + share tools — whereas OmniDazzle is small, simple and tailor-made for this task.

Comment: For anyone else who runs across this, OmniDazzle is no longer developed and doesn't seem to work with recent versions of OS X: https://support.omnigroup.com/omnidazzle-troubleshooting/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [video of the process](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhMFxFtNOEI) using [Skitch](http://skitch.com/)

[image]

Comment: Great video @peelman, but could you perhaps elaborate on the features of Skitch?

Comment: Its a free utility that is like Cmd-Shift-3 and Cmd-Shift-4 (OSX's built in screen shot hot keys) on speed.  It lets you grab the screen, or a portion of the screen, edit it, then post it to either myskitch.com or a webserver of your choosing (via most standard methods, ftp, sftp, webdav, etc).  Its utility can only be truly explained by using it.