# Mac screenshot and highlight (like mousepose)

Tags: mac, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a screen shot with emphasis](https://superuser.com/questions/153732/how-do-i-create-a-screen-shot-with-emphasis)

Lets say you want to take a screenshot of a form on a website but you want to highlight a particular part of the form, maybe a field of some type.

Usually you have to:
 1. take a screenshot (maybe apple+shift+4)
 2. open paint/photoshop and open the screenshot
 3. highlight the field in a colour of some sort (red box)
 4. save and then send

Is there some better workflow? 
I it would be great to have a application that would highlight the field and then let you capture the screenshot. Mousepose doesn't quite work cause the highlighting still follows your mouse pointer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could also:

```
f=`date +'%y%m%d-%H%M%S.png'`; cd ~/Desktop; screencapture -io $f && open -a 'Adobe Photoshop CS5' $f
```

and [Bind a key to a commandline command in Mac OS X? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/bind-a-key-to-a-commandline-command-in-mac-os-x/264943#264943).

At least no more opening the image editor, pasting a new document and saving (as).

Answer (score 1):

Possible dupe of: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/153732/how-do-i-create-a-screen-shot-with-emphasis/153852#153852).

I would look at [Skitch](http://skitch.com).  It allows you to snap a screenshot via selecting a portion of the screen, or by grabbing an entire window, desktop, etc., then apply various overlays, such as highlights, arrows, wording, etc, and allows you to drag the resulting image to another app, or post it to a web server with one click (a second click will copy the resulting URL to your clipboard).  I've used it heavily for a couple of years now.

Examples:

- [using iTerm](https://superuser.com/questions/158750/how-to-use-iterm-with-quicksilver/158768#158768)
- [Server 2k8 Environment Vars](https://superuser.com/questions/178008/windows-server-2008-r2-environment-variables/178011#178011)
- [Video of Using Skitch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhMFxFtNOEI)